# Laravel Mass Updates without touching timestamps

Tags: laravel, timestamp

if single update we can use

```
$variable->timestamps = false;
```

but how if i want to mass updates without touching timestamps.

currently my code is

```
$allapps = App::select('id','name','parent_id','view')->where('published',true)->whereNotIn('id', $excludeappsid)->update(['timestamps' => false],['view' => 0]);
```

but i get error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'timestamps' in
>   'field list'

any solution?

thanks.

Comment: How are you doing a select and an update in the same query?

Comment: Doesn't that kind of defeat  the purpose of the updated_at field?

Comment: with this query i just want to reset pageview counter, so i dont need to update updated_at field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. I don't think it should even be possible.

You can however use the query builder directly without Eloquent and this will not update the timestamps.

```
\DB::table(with(App::class)->getTable())
    ->where('published', true)
    ->whereNotIn('id', $excludeappsid)
    ->update(['view' => 0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```php
$model = new App();
$model->timestamps = false;
App::setModel($model)
    ->where('published',true)
    ->whereNotIn('id', $excludeappsid)
    ->update(['view' => 0]);
```

Comment: please explain your answer.

Comment: Laravel Eloquent Builder try to "addUpdatedAtColumn" during updates, if the model has updated_at column, Eloquent Builder will add this column to value array. When doting this, the method will check class property "$model" uses timestamps or not. if you try to disable timestamps temporarily you can set timestamps property to false in your model instances and pass that model at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal with the query below:

```
App::select('id','name','parent_id','view')
    ->where('published',true)
    ->whereNotIn('id', $excludeappsid)
    ->update([
        'view' => 0,

        // Change updated_at column if its different from yours
        'updated_at' => \DB::raw('updated_at'),
    ]);
```

Actually it updates **updated_at** column, but the **query will change it with the old value**.

Answer (score 0):

Since your model, you can juste mark timestamps to false

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Or you can do nothing. :)

```
    $allapps = App::select('id','name','parent_id','view')
                   ->where('published',true)
                   ->whereNotIn('id', $excludeappsid)
                   ->update(['view' => 0])
```

Comment: if i touch the model with that change, i have to touch so many controller

Comment: And What happens when you only update what you want without search to update `created_at` and `updated_at` ?

Comment: with this query i just want to reset pageview counter, so i dont need to update updated_at field,